# Ruby, Rails console start with error...need help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
> luke@Macbook-Pro~/Documents/workspace/RoR/rails_projects/sample4_app$ ruby -v

ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-darwin10.8.0]
luke@Macbook-Pro~/Documents/workspace/RoR/rails_projects/sample4_app$ rails -v

Rails 3.0.9

luke@Macbook-Pro~/Documents/workspace/RoR/rails_projects/sample4_app$ rails console


/Users/luke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10.8.0/readline.bundle: dlopen(/Users/luke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10.8.0/readline.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _rl_basic_quote_characters (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/luke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10.8.0/readline.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/luke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10.8.0/readline.bundle - /Users/luke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10.8.0/readline.bundle
    from /Users/luke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/completion.rb:10
    from /Users/luke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
    from /Users/luke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3
    from /Users/luke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:20:in `require'
    from /Users/luke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:20
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Ruby is okay, Rails is okay, but "rails console"
Need help
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suggest using bundler to manage the gems in your project.

If you put

```
 source 'http://rubygems.org'

 gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
```

in your Gemfile (see also http://gembundler.com/ )

Then

```
 bundle install
```

will install the correct version of rails and

```
 bundle exec rails console
```

will start up your console.  `bundle exec rails server` will start the server, etc.

You might also want to consider using `rvm` to install and manage your rubies if you aren't already -- http://beginrescueend.com/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a file in your ruby build. Did you just recently update to OS X 10.7? You might need a fresh reinstall of Rails. As always this can be done with:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Sorry I can't be of more help.